# React.cloneElement issue (React Top-Level API)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am playing with React Top-Level API to get a feel how it works and I can't get it to clone a component.

I have a UserButton component that should clone Button component but add a text in the beginning.

Live code: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-cloneelement-issue-4j2ur?file=/src/App.js

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="gap-2 flex">
      <Button>Login</Button>

      {/* Expected to get a button that says:
            "Hello! nice to see you Alex"*/}
      <UserButton>Alex</UserButton>
    </div>
  );
}

export function Button({ children, label, className }) {
  return (
    <div
      className={`py-2 px-4 bg-purple-800 hover:bg-purple-900 inline-block rounded text-white cursor-pointer ${className}`}
    >
      {label} {children}
    </div>
  );
}

export function UserButton() {
  // React.cloneElement not working
  return React.cloneElement(Button, {
    label: "Hello! nice to see you"
  });
}
```

The error I am getting:

> Error Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: I don't think this is the explanation for the error you're seeing, but `cloneElement` takes a "React element" as its first argument, not a component. That means instead of passing the component `Button`, you need an "instantiated component", `Button(props)`. EDIT: actually, reading it closer, this might be in fact exactly the problem: elements have a "type" property but component classes/functions do not

Comment: @RobinZigmond thanks, I tried "Button(props)" but it is still not working. I get "props is not defined"

Comment: Obviously I didn't mean literally that, I just meant you had to pass the result of calling me Button function. I don't know what actual props you want to give it - I'm really not sure what you're trying to do - I was merely ecpla the problem with how you were calling cloneElement.

Comment: @RobinZigmond is it possible to show an example? would really help.... Still not getting it. It works fine when I use it in a map but as single not

Comment: I'm not sure what you are after. You can find plenty of examples of using `React.cloneElement` online - just try googling. Note that these examples are almost always when mapping over React children - I don't think what you are trying to do here really makes sense. Most likely whatever problem you are trying to solve can be done without `cloneElement` at all.